# Mutate DataFrames in Julia

Tags: julia, dplyr

Looking for a function that works like `by` but doesn't collapse my DataFrame. In R I would use `dplyr`'s `groupby(b) %>% mutate(x1 = sum(a))`. I don't want to lose information from the table such as that in variable `:c`.

```
mydf = DataFrame(a = 1:4, b = repeat(1:2,2), c=4:-1:1)
bypreserve(mydf, :b,  x -> sum(x.a))
│ Row │ a     │ b     │ c     │ x1
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │Int64 
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤───────
│ 1   │ 1     │ 1     │ 4     │ 4
│ 2   │ 2     │ 2     │ 3     │ 6
│ 3   │ 3     │ 1     │ 2     │ 4
│ 4   │ 4     │ 2     │ 1     │ 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this functionality is discussed, but I would say that it will take several months to be shipped (the general idea is to allow `select` to have `groupby` keyword argument + also add `transform` function that will work like `select` but preserve columns of the source data frame).

For now the solution is to use `join` after `by`:

```
join(mydf, by(mydf, :b, x1 = :a => sum), on=:b)
```